# Ubuntu 22.06, Android Studio, emulator will not load virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-virtual-device, uninstallation

I installed Android Studio on my Ubuntu PC a week ago, but when I try to run a virtual device that I have created - no phone appears in the emulator and, eventually, the emulator times out.

I always get a error message "Application has failed to install".

The app itself is literally the "hello android" template app.

Thanks very much for the help! I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, so if any answers require complex programming - feel free to explain in as much detail as you think is required!

I have tried:

-Enabling cpu virtualization in bios(amd)

- wipe data in AS device manager
- cold boot in AS device manager
- changing to an earlier device and Android OS in AVD
- uninstalling AS and reinstalling AS, though this was only a partial reinstall.

I'm expecting to see a virtual representation of my virtual device appear in the emulator, that will run my app.

Answer (score 1):

managed to fix the issue!

Firstly, the software had completely uninstalled - I just hadn't restarted the PC so the Android Studio icon was still displaying.

The problem is caused by my graphics card. Although I have the latest nvidia driver (525 at time of writing), something sus is clearly happening; when I change the "Graphics" setting of the "Emulated Performance" section on the AVD manager to use Software instead of Automatic or Hardware it works.

Hurray! And I hope this answer helps anyone else who has the same problem.

Cheers,